# Item Level Targeting not working for printer deployment GPO

Tags: windows, printing, group-policy

I have a GPO that deploys a shared printer (seperate windows print server VM) via User Configuration - Preferences - Control Panel Settings - Printers.

I have selected 'Run in logged-on user's security context'. And set up Item Level Targeting. If I set to target a user and run gpupdate the printer will install. If I set to target a security group and run gpupdate the printer will not install.

I have confirmed a million times that the user is a member of the security group. At this point I am only testing for a single user.

Why is it not working if I target a group?

Comment: So turns out you need to remove the domain portion of of the group after select the group from the '...' button. So 'GroupName' instead of 'DomainName\GroupName'. I dont know why this works prehaps someone can comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "Domain" For the security group when selecting it in the Targeting Editor.